# Is React Native multi-processed or just multi-threaded in the current app?

Tags: multithreading, react-native

The following article mentioned that React Native is multi-processed (with each process contains one thread instead of being multi-threaded):
https://brooklinmyers.medium.com/react-native-understanding-threads-e026c7d62bb2.
I wonder if it's the right statement.

At least, isn't the UI thread (which should be responsible to communicate with the main thread of the App for UI rendering) and the native module thread in the same process?

And actually, the official document doesn't mention about multi-processes at all:
https://reactnative.dev/architecture/threading-model.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the same process. RN running multiple processes, each process will contains one thread